# Can't find playlist uri after adding it to an account

Tags: python, uri, youtube-api

I'm trying to make a few playlists that contain videos I've located through the YouTube API.  This python code creates the playlists fine:

```
ptitlestart = 'Cute Videos'
ptitlecount = 1

while ptitlecount < 6:
  new_private_playlistentry = yt_service.AddPlaylist(ptitlestart + str(ptitlecount), 'cute pets video playlist for content coding', True)
  ptitlecount = ptitlecount + 1
```

But I can't figure out how to find the uri's of the playlists I've just created.  I need the uri of each playlist in order to add videos to it.  Wisdom appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this using [version 3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) of the YouTube API, since that has much better support for Python.

Here's a snippet of code that creates a new playlist and prints out the playlist's id:

```
playlists_insert_response = youtube.playlists().insert(
  part="snippet",
  body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title="Test Playlist",
      description="A playlist created with the YouTube API v3"
    )
  )
).execute()

print "New playlist id: %s" % playlists_insert_response["id"]
```